# GridView ASP.NET - passing a command and a ID to the code-behind

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview

What is the correct way to pass a command and an identity Id (int) back to a code behind in ASP.NET. I'm looking at CommandName and CommandArgument. Am I reading it wrong but I think CommandArgument passes back the display index. How does this help?

Can't figure out how I can set CommandArugment to the ID that I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the **CommandName** and **CommandArgument** fields in the GridView then you can access those values in the code behind.

So say you have an image button in every row and when a user selects the button you want to access the command name and parameter for that row.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwRecords" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="objRecords" OnRowCommand="gvwRecords_RowCommand">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderImageUrl="~/Images/Approve_Header_Dark.gif">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnApprove" %>' 
          CausesValidation="false" AlternateText="Approve record" ImageUrl="~/Images/Unapproved.gif" 
          CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In the code behind:

```
protected void gvwRecords_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int recordID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    if (recordID > 0)
    {
       switch (e.CommandName.ToLower())
       {
          case "sort":
             break;
          case "approve":
             Record.ApproveRecord(recordID);
             gvwRecords.DataBind();
             break;
           ...
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the DataItem associated with that index and get any value you need from it. 
Here is a linik showing some ways to do this...

http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/88462.aspx

Comment: Good info. I like this approach too. +1